# Frequent Reauthentication Requests with GCP Organization Account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I am experiencing an issue with my organization's Google Workspace account used on Google Cloud Platform (GCP), which is registered with a domain from Google Domains. Unlike my personal Gmail account (something@gmail.com), I am frequently prompted to re-enter my password every few hours while accessing the GCP website or performing CLI authentications, such as 'Firebase Login'.

This issue becomes particularly evident when using the Firebase CLI. After logging in with 'Firebase Login', I am unable to execute 'Firebase Deploy' due to an authentication error. The only workaround I've found is to execute 'Firebase logout' and then 'Firebase login' again, which requires me to re-authenticate via the browser. Notably, this problem does not occur when I use my personal Gmail account.

As the owner of the Google Workspace domain account, I find this frequent reauthentication process quite frustrating. Could you please guide me on how to modify the settings to allow persistent authentication, similar to what is experienced with personal accounts on GCP?

Tried to look for any rules regarding this both on Google Workspace and GCP security tab but failed to find one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you answer yes to these questions, Google will require you to authenticate more often:

- you are using an account with admin level permissions
- you do not have MFA enabled
- you do not have recovery accounts set up
- you authenticate from different locations or risky locations

To reduce authorization interactions, complete each step in the security [checklist](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9184226)

The most important items are to enable MFA and not use an account with admin level permissions.

Note: create accounts that follow **least privileged principles**. Get in the habit of using Admin accounts only when required and restricted user accounts for most of your work.